# Deleting all occurrences of triples in a list, according to the triples first value

Tags: haskell

I have a list of triples in the form `[(String, String, Int)]`, and I am trying to delete all elements in the list that have the same value in the first String position.

Currently i have tried this, where testData is my list of triples.

```
removeElem :: String -> [(String, String, Int)]
removeElem x = map (\p@(a, b, c) -> if (a == x) then head (delete (a, b, c) testData) else p) testData
```

If `testData = [("Hello", "Yes", 50), ("Goodbye", "Sky", 80), ("Hello", "Apple", 100)]` I want the function to delete all triples that have "Hello" as their first value. The function I wrote only deletes the first triple it finds that matches.

I am new to Haskell and am unsure what else to try.

Comment: You want `filter`, not `map` for this. You do not need `head` nor `delete`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `filter`, not `map`:

```
removeElem :: String -> [(String, String, Int)]
removeElem x = filter (\(a,_,_) -> x /= a)
```

Comment: Thank you very much this was much simpler and easier to read than what i was trying to do!

Comment: One thing you can know for sure about `map` is that it can't add or remove elements to/from the list.